# How to replace KingrootSU with Superuser Elite?

Tags: rooting, tablet, superuser

Just rooted my new Chinese tablet - an adventure for me. I used Kingroot apk. It uses KingrootSU app as GUI manager for superuser permission. I want to use my Superuser Elite instead though. How can I do so?

Comment: "*My attempts were near disaster*" -- please elaborate in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this [tool](http://www.mediafire.com/download/mxzbt42xypvn2ts/Replace_Kinguser_with_SuperSU-v2.4.zip) and this [guide](http://zidroid.com/how-to-get-ride-and-replace-kinguser-with-supersu-app/). I used it myself on LG G3, because Kingroot was my last resort for rooting.

It definitely worked, but there was one Kingroot app left over, called Purify, which I guess was added to Kingroot after the script was made, so I would suggest adding the following lines to the script:

```
am kill com.kingroot.purify
pm uninstall com.kingroot.purify
rm /system/app/purify.apk >/dev/null
rm -r /system/app/purify>/dev/null
```

Or, what I did was once I had supersu installed, to be totally sure that Kingroot was gone, I installed TWRP, then completely erased the normal partition and installed Cyanogenmod 13.0.

good luck!